# javascript array empty and undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a question about empty and undefined in array

please see my codes bottom

```
const arr = []
arr[1]=1
arr[2]=2
arr[3]=3
arr[5]=5
console.log(arr[4])// console: undefined
console.log(arr)// console: [empty, 1,2,3,empty,5]
```

so I didn't understand difference between two colsole result

why console.log(arr[4]) is undefined but console.log(arr)'s index 4 is empty?

please help me thank you

Comment: It is just console showing you 'empty' symbol so you may know that explicit 'undefined' is not pushed in the array but you didn't enter anything for the same index. so if you check `arr[4] === ''` it will return you false and if you check it against `arr[4] === undefined` it will return you `true`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I just wanted to point out that "thanks please help" phrases are discouraged in Stack Overflow, people here will help if we can so there is no need for adding "help" statements. Good question by the way, have a great day! :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you read a property which doesn’t exist you get the value `undefined`. That’s standard JS.

When you log a whole array, you aren’t reading the property explicitly, so the console helpfully distinguishes between “has no value” and “explicitly has the `undefined` value”.

Answer (score 2):

The word `empty` is added by the console interface of the browser.

The correct state of an unassigned array element is `undefined` - and this is given to you by JS when you try to access it. Besides this, the interpretation of unassigned array elements is subjected to the system which interprets it.

Here are some examples:

```js
let arr = new Array(2);

console.log(arr[0]);    //undefined

console.log(arr);       //In SO - [undefined, undefined]. In browser [empty x 2]    

console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));   // [null, null]
```